# Can not open files with c

Tags: c, fopen

Im supposed to write a program that opens an excel file, reads the numbers on the file, multiplies them by 9.8 and the shows the answer in another excel gile.

I wrote this, and I did not get any errors in the compiler, but when I run it, it does not open any files. How do I make it open the files?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *archivo;
    FILE *archivoSalida;

    int masa;
    float peso;

    archivo = fopen("C:/Users/nacho/Documents/UNAM/Informatica/proyecto/archivoEntrada.txt", "r");
    archivoSalida = fopen("C:/Users/nacho/Documents/UNAM/Informatica/proyecto/archivoSalida.txt", "r");

    if (archivo != NULL) 
    {  
        printf("The file was opened succesully");

        while (fscanf(archivo,"%d", &masa)!= EOF)
        {
            peso=masa*9.81;
            fprintf(archivoSalida, "%f\n", peso);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Error");
    }


    fclose(archivo);
    fclose(archivoSalida);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You'll want to `fopen` the output file ("archivoSalida") with mode `"w"` (for *write*) instead of `"r"` (for *read*). See e.g. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html.
2. You do check if the input file could be opened (`if (archivo != NULL)`). Why don't you do the same for the output file?
3. Upon an error, you should output *which* error occured from `errno`, e.g. via [`perror(...)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/perror.html). That should help in finding the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your file denominated by `archivoSalida` is opened in read mode (`'r'`).

You should also check the return codes of read/writes functions to be sure everything happen as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The file names look Windows-ish.  Is it possible that all of the forward slashes (`/`) that you have in both file names should really be back slashes (`\`)?

Comment: As far as I know, any implementation of the C standard library for Windows is very lenient about the direction of slashes.

Comment: That would make life a lot easier if that is the case.  All of my C code is on linux so I wasn't sure.